# Is it a good practice to make one Spring bean inherit another one?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, spring-bean

In my Spring Boot web application there are two beans, one of them inherits other one and both implements an interface. Something line this:

```java
@Component 
public class A implements SomeInterface {
    // ....
} 

@Component 
public class B extends A implements SomeInterface {
    // ....
}
```

Is it a good idea to make one bean extending another one or it's better use a decorator? And why?

I don't mean any specific case but general one.

Comment: if you're going to use both, then I don't see why not. But really I can't even remember last time I've personally had similar situation. Most of the time if I extend `A` it would be abstract class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No because it will fail if you inject it by interface or the super class. If you inject A now it is ambiguous.

Comment: but this a qualifier would solve, no?

Comment: Yeah - or you make A Primary. But I advocate against it.

Comment: I am not in favor of this approach, just saying that this argument can be bypassed somehow

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich so you're giving an opinion.

Comment: @Cwrwhaf Regarding the code present in the question: No. That code will not work when trying to inject an instance of `SomeInterface` or `A`. Regarding the comment about including a qualifier: Yes. That's why I used the term "advocate against it".

Answer (score 0):

Asking if it's good practice is a bit of ambiguous question which only really gathers opinion.
One way of using your interfaces is to  `@Autowire` all instances of the implementing classes and call a method on each of them

```
@Autowired
List<SomeInterface> someInterfaces;


public void someAction(SomeObject object) {
    for(SomeInterface someInterface: someInterfaces) {
        someInterface.doSomething(object);
    }
}
```